# How & When does User equipment gets to know what is the SFN(system frame number) during Handover process?

Tags: network, lte, 5g, 4g, 3g

> Take an example:
>
> - UE camps to an LTE network let's say LTE B66. Network sends RRC reconfiguration to measure the neighbor cells.
> - UE scans & sends measurement report reporting neighbor cells. Now network sent RRC reconfiguration (handover command) to another cell
>   which has good signal conditions than the serving cell.

*Based on my understanding after decoding the RRC reconfiguration UE will know the target PCI, RACH Information*.

*Also I'm not sure if we decode mib & sib 1 of target cell during HO process ?*

If we do not decode the target cell mib & sib 1 then how do we perform downlink synchronization i.e. how does UE get to know what is the SFN ?*According to me we get System Frame Number decoded in Master Information Block (MIB) in Physical Broadcast channel (PBCH)*

**Can anyone point me out:**

- **[1] How/When does UE get to know what is the SFN during HO process ?**
- **[2] Do we actually decode mib & sib 1 of target cell during HO process ?**

Thanks.